# Fiware: Manager & IoT Agent relationship - IDAS

Tags: agent, fiware

I have installed the IDAS Backend Device Manager and the UltraLight IoT Agent. After executing it, I see two processes running: one is the agent and the other the manager. But I don't know which one is the exact functionality of this manager.

- Are required both the agent and the manager to connect the context broker with a device?
- Can this communication happen using only the agent?
- Is the manager in charge of receiving all the messages from the devices and to forwarding them to the corresponding agent?
- Is the manager simply an admin API to manage the installed agents and the devices?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Manager is not needed for small/medium IoT deployments. So generally you will not need it. The Manager is used for large settings where multiple IoT Agents of different types handle lots of devices.
   You can read more about the manager in the documentation at the github.
2. As explained in (1), yes.
3. It is actually the contrary, a northbound umbrella so the ContextBroker or other northbound elements may talk only with one entity that proxies all IoT Agents.
4. A bit of that but also it may concentrate all ContextBroker - IoT Agents comms.

Thanks for using IDAS!
Cheers,